# Login hangs on spotlight and no network is available

Tags: macos, spotlight, login

After upgrading to Lion, I boot up and most of my icons don't appear on the right side of the top menu bar and when I hover over spotlight, I get the spinning pinwheel and there's no network access.  The preferences open up fine but when I click on network, it hangs.

The only way I can get around it is to reboot while holding down the shift key.

I read about a fix (that didn't work for me) that clears the font caches by executing:

```
atsutil databases -removeUser
atsutil server -shutdown
atsutil server -ping
```

And another fix suggestion that said to use FontNuke & check the "Reset Spotlight" and "Repair Permissions" boxes before clicking "Nuke Font Caches".  However, FontNuke isn't available yet for Lion.

Has anyone else had this problem and found a way to fix it?

Update: The new version of FontNuke is out yet it didn't fix my problem.  Still SOL.

Anyone see this and have any ideas?

Comment: Once you boot into safe mode, you might consider clearing out all the apps that launch at log in and substitute activity monitor (and set up the window to sort by CPU and show disk IO at the bottom) as well as console app (system.log might be good - all messages would have more info and might be better...) That way you can see exactly which processes are getting stuck or working when the problems start.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off Spotlight indexing for the whole hard drive in System Preferences -> Spotlight.
Then after rebooting turn it on again, and Spotlight will re-index.

My problem is that I'm having this problem every other or every third reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem; I found a workaround (far from calling this a solution...): downloaded the last version of fintnuke, bot the system in safe moe holding shift during startup, run FontNuke using Admin Free Nuke with the reset spotlight index checked. After rebooting everything works, but if you restart the problem is still there...so this is not a real solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. In my case it was because of a hard disk error. When I ran a volume check on the system volume in the disk utility (Utilities->Disk Utility) I got an error message. So I took my snow leopard CD and booted from the CD. In the installation surface I started the Disk Utility again and repaired my system volume. Afterwards I was able to start Lion again without any problems.